# Unity crash on iOS - GameObject.SendMessage

Tags: c#, ios, exception, unity-game-engine, crash

Unity Version: 5.3.2p2

It's crashing from within Unity's internal code when doing a GameObject.SendMessage() call, it should be noted that this particular line itself is not the source of the crash (nothing in this line of code is null):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

// Attached to a large Image that blocks all input, OnPointerClick filters to a "target"
public class OnboardingArrowInputBlocker : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public MonoBehaviour target;

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (target)
        {
            // Line that leads to the crash (crashes in Unity's internal code, not here):
            target.gameObject.SendMessage("OnPointerClick", eventData, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
        }
    }
}
```

My best guess is that somehwere in Unity's SendMessage code, an exception occurs when it tries to find a valid target to invoke the OnPointerClick message. This would mean the crash happens before we ever invoke the OnPointerClick callback on the target and not within the body of its callback (because that would show up in the trace). It seems like I will need to open a support ticket with Unity if it's an internal problem in their code.

Let me know if there's more information I can share about my issue. Thanks all!

Stack trace:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  game-app                       0x100033770 CrashedCheckBellowForHintsWhy() (CrashReporter.mm:97)
1  game-app                       0x100cbfe10 RuntimeInvoker_Void_t2779279689_Object_t_Object_t(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**) (Il2CppInvokerTable.cpp:1128)
2  game-app                       0x101613d94 il2cpp::vm::Runtime::CallUnhandledExceptionDelegate(Il2CppDomain*, Il2CppDelegate*, Il2CppObject*) (Runtime.cpp:350)
3  game-app                       0x101613d14 il2cpp::vm::Runtime::UnhandledException(Il2CppObject*) (Runtime.cpp:433)
4  game-app                       0x100ee6ee4 ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingException**, bool) (ScriptingInvocation.cpp:202)
5  game-app                       0x100edd0f8 MonoBehaviour::InvokeMethodOrCoroutineChecked(ScriptingMethodIl2Cpp, ScriptingObject*, ScriptingException**) (MonoBehaviour.cpp:839)
6  game-app                       0x100edd2dc MonoBehaviour::InvokeMethodOrCoroutineChecked(ScriptingMethodIl2Cpp, ScriptingObject*) (MonoBehaviour.cpp:859)
7  game-app                       0x100eeb920 Scripting::SendScriptingMessage(Unity::GameObject&, char const*, ScriptingObject*) (BaseObject.h:87)
8  game-app                       0x101105784 GameObject_CUSTOM_SendMessage(ReadOnlyScriptingObjectOfType<Unity::GameObject>, ICallString, ScriptingObject*, int) (UnityEngineGameObjectBindings.gen.cpp:320)
9  game-app                       0x100166628 OnboardingArrowInputBlocker_Message2dObjects_m1580627665 (Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_14.cpp:6437)
10 game-app                       0x1001660ac OnboardingArrowInputBlocker_OnPointerClick_m3735897309 (Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_14.cpp:6148)
11 game-app                       0x1009f6848 ExecuteEvents_Execute_TisObject_t_m1533897725_gshared (GenericMethods0.cpp:35043)
12 game-app                       0x1007d90e4 StandaloneInputModule_ProcessTouchPress_m2953705401 (Bulk_UnityEngine.UI_0.cpp:8133)
13 game-app                       0x1007d8d08 StandaloneInputModule_ProcessTouchEvents_m3567487943 (Bulk_UnityEngine.UI_0.cpp:7836)
14 game-app                       0x1007d8684 StandaloneInputModule_Process_m3720469665 (Bulk_UnityEngine.UI_0.cpp:7775)
15 game-app                       0x100cbfba4 RuntimeInvoker_Void_t2779279689(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**) (Il2CppInvokerTable.cpp:1072)
16 game-app                       0x1016136b0 il2cpp::vm::Runtime::Invoke(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**, Il2CppObject**) (Runtime.cpp:350)
17 game-app                       0x100ee7128 ScriptingInvocationNoArgs::Invoke(ScriptingException**) (ScriptingInvocationNoArgs.cpp:111)
18 game-app                       0x100ee70e0 ScriptingInvocationNoArgs::Invoke() (ScriptingInvocationNoArgs.cpp:95)
19 game-app                       0x100edc670 MonoBehaviour::CallUpdateMethod(int) (MonoBehaviour.cpp:456)
20 game-app                       0x100dafb38 void BaseBehaviourManager::CommonUpdate<BehaviourManager>() (Behaviour.cpp:169)
21 game-app                       0x100e97d24 PlayerLoop(bool, bool, IHookEvent*) (Player.cpp:1727)
22 game-app                       0x10110e2b0 UnityPlayerLoopImpl(bool) (LibEntryPoint.mm:239)
23 game-app                       0x10002a41c UnityRepaint (UnityAppController+Rendering.mm:236)
24 game-app                       0x10002a25c -[UnityAppController(Rendering) repaintDisplayLink] (UnityAppController+Rendering.mm:52)
25 QuartzCore                     0x186933814 CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 40
26 QuartzCore                     0x1869336c8 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 424
27 IOKit                          0x18445e1e8 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 372
28 CoreFoundation                 0x18418b1f8 __CFMachPortPerform + 180
29 CoreFoundation                 0x1841a1634 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
30 CoreFoundation                 0x1841a0d6c __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436
31 CoreFoundation                 0x18419eac4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1800
32 CoreFoundation                 0x1840cd680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
33 GraphicsServices               0x1855dc088 GSEventRunModal + 180
34 UIKit                          0x188f44d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
35 game-app                       0x10002455c main (main.mm:32)
36 libdyld.dylib                  0x183c6e8b8 start + 4
```

Comment: ? you can't "send" an OnPointerClick yourself. I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @MickyD The only code you're not seeing is the remainder of the Unity standard OnPointerClick method:
https://gist.github.com/blaketriana/b954dd255038c2bcab5d

Comment: @JoeBlow It can be done, try it in a sample project.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Change `SendMessage("OnPointerClick"...)` to `SendMessage("MissPiggy"...)`.  If that works then you know to avoid such  reserved terms.   Besides, why the `SendMessage` anyway?  Just implement `IPointerClickHandler` on all interested parties and let Unity take care of it :)

Comment: @MickyD Yeah, I ended up going with the IPointerClickHandler for the sake of getting something out that doesn't crash since the actual crash takes place somewhere in Unity's search for valid invocation targets. I'm considering in closing this question since it seems better to ask Unity in a support ticket, thought I'd ask here in case anyone else had seen it.

Comment: @MickyD It's not a 100% repro. I'm guessing my specific state in my game has some specific hierarchy detail that hits an edge case in Unity's IL2CPP ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(). Playing through it every which way doesn't crash me, this trace came from the wild on Crashlytics.

Comment: Oki.  See how you go with using `IPointerClickHandler` everywhere.  Good luck!